Let m be an integer greater than 2, prove that for any positive integer n, $2^n+1$ is not divisible by $2^m-1$
The answer uses proof by contradiction by assuming a minimum n and proving that n-m also satisfies, but I don't really know the thinking process behind this construction. Are there any hidden observations that could inform the use of the method?

It seems likely to be a straightforward use of the division algorithm in a slightly unfamiliar context. How would you proceed with the analysis if you had $x$ instead of $2$ and were dealing with polynomials?

It boils down to the fact that $a_n = 2^n-1$ is a strong divisibility sequence so we can apply the Euclidean gcd algorithm to the exponents, as explained here in the dupe, Your subtraction amount to using the "slow" subtractive form of the Euclidean algorithm with reduction step $\gcd(m,n) = \gcd(m,n-m).\ \ $
